# Laravel - Blade outputs variable that i add to

Tags: variables, laravel-blade, laravel-5

Being new to laravel this rather simple thing confuses me. Notice the below

```
{{ $i = 0}}
@foreach($openhours as $id => $day)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$id}}</td>
        <td>{{$day}}</td>
        <td>{{$note[$i]}}</td>
    </tr> 
    {{ $i++ }}
@endforeach
```

As the above shows i simply iterate over an array where i also output a specific index from another array. There is then added one to the index on each iteration. The above works, but my problem is that blade also outputs `$i`

How can i prevent this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent this behaviour by using PHP tags directly in blade. Though this defeats the whole purpose, and it is usually an indication you're not doing something right if you have to do this. However heres a fix.

```
<?php $i = 0 ?>
@foreach($openhours as $id => $day)
<tr>
    <td>{{$id}}</td>
    <td>{{$day}}</td>
    <td>{{$note[$i]}}</td>
</tr> 
<?php $i++ ?>
@endforeach
```

The curly braces in blade translates to `<?php echo ?>` so your variable is showing because you have done this `<?php echo i++ ?>`

Comment: Makes sense.. I actually found a whole other solution so i do not need to have a iterate counter. But for reference i also stumbled upon a more "bladish" solution, which i wasnt particulary glad to use: `{{-- /$i=0;/ --}}` however that worked too. But again i found another solution where no iterator was required.

Comment: Okay, you should mark the answer because it actually solves the issue